# In Perl, how to use plus operator for arithmetic calculation in print statement?

Tags: perl

I have the following small Perl (v5.10) program:

```
use strict;

my @nums;
my $i = 0;

while ($i < 5) {

    print "Enter number " . $i+1 . ": ";
    $nums[$i] = <STDIN>;
    $i++;
}

foreach (@nums) {

    chomp $_;
    print "$_\t";
}
print "\n";
```

This is the result of a test run:

```
1: 2
1: 1
1: 6
1: 3
1: 2
2   1   6   3   2
```

The problem, as you can see, is that the print statement prompting the user for input isn't functioning as expected. Instead of "Enter number 1: " or "Enter number 3:", e.t.c., I just get "1:". I didn't expect this to work to be honest because I know that the + operator has been overloaded for string concatenation in Perl. How do I get around this problem? And what is the reason for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`+` is not overloaded. It is a precedence issue. The expression is parsed as

```
print(((('Enter number ' . $i) + 1) . ': '));
```

Which is the same as

```
print((0 + 1) . ': ');
```

You can use

```
perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e 'print "Enter number " . $i+1 . ": ";'
```

to see how Perl parses your scripts.

Adding parentheses sovles the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Although your immediate problem is incorrect assumption of operator precedence, I see another two (potential) issues that might be interesting as well.

First, it makes little sense using `$i + 1`, when you can just start your 'output' index from 1, end with 5, but use `push` to fill the array instead.

Second, it's a bit weird seeing `chomp` at the output phase of the script, where in fact it should be done in the input phase (as you try to *collect* numbers from user, don't you?)

For example:

```
use warnings; use strict;

my @numbers;
for my $i (1..5) {
  print "Enter number $i: ";
  chomp(my $number = <STDIN>);
  push @numbers, $number;
}

print "$_\t" for @numbers;
print "\n";
```